# Prevent jQuery.ajax() from sending automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqxhr

I need to do some (potentially asynchronous) stuff before sending an AJAX-request via jQuery.
Is there any way to evoke the sending of the request on a jqXHR object manually?
The problem is that I need to immediately return the jqXHR object (e.g. to use the $.Deferred() interface)

Comment: Don't call `$.ajax` until you want to send the request?

Comment: The `jQuery.ajax()` function already immediately returns the `jqXhr` object. Could you provide more details - and some code - showing what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Not that I know of... if you provide more information about your problem, we might be able to come up with an alternative solution. You know that you can always create your own promise objects?

Comment: Under a certain condition I want to perform another request before I perform the current one. COnsequently, I cannot use beforeSend since it is not asynchron.

Comment: But I also have to return the jqXHR of the future request immediately

Answer (score 1):

you can use `beforeSend` event in jQuery

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "url",
      beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
      // you can do here 
      }
    }).done(function ( data ) {
     .............
    });
```

[see here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @Leo Selig did you checked my solution